# DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

In WPF, when deriving a control from a base control, you add this in the constructor.

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MediaPlayer), new StyledPropertyMetadata(typeof(MediaPlayer)));
```

How do you convert this to Avalonia UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IStyleable` interface and set `StyleKey` to your type.

```
public class MyGrid : Grid, IStyleable
{
    Type IStyleable.StyleKey => typeof(MyGrid);
}
```

Comment: The thing is, you probably don't need to. Default implementation is `Type IStyleable.StyleKey => GetType();`, so desired behavior happens automatically.